# How to get HMODULE from COM object that it reside?

Tags: visual-c++, com, webbrowser-control

I want to determine the version of DLL that implemented `Microsoft Web Browser Control`. The way I need to go is query `DLLVERSIONINFO` from implemented DLL through `DllGetVersion` function; because I think it is the most stable way. But, I don't known how to get `HMODULE` of implemented DLL from `Microsoft Web Browser Control` object.

How can I get the `HMODULE` of implemented DLL? Or there is other way to determine its version with stability?

Thanks for advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can read Internet Explorer COM Object's server from the registry (ususally, it will be hosted by [shdocvw.dll](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa741313.aspx) or ieframe.dll in more recent versions), and load it manually, something like this:

```
TCHAR key[MAX_PATH];
// read CLSID_InternetExplorer COM Server path
SHRegGetPath(HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT, _T("CLSID\\{8856F961-340A-11D0-A96B-00C04FD705A2}\\InProcServer32"), NULL, key, 0);
HINSTANCE hInstance = LoadLibrary(PathFindFileName(key));
if (hInstance)
{
    DLLGETVERSIONPROC fn = (DLLGETVERSIONPROC)GetProcAddress(hInstance, "DllGetVersion");
    if (fn)
    {
        DLLVERSIONINFO2 version;
        ZeroMemory(&version, sizeof(DLLVERSIONINFO2));
        version.info1.cbSize = sizeof(DLLVERSIONINFO2);
        (*fn)((DLLVERSIONINFO*)&version);

        printf("Major:%u\n", version.ullVersion >> 48);
        printf("Minor:%u\n", (version.ullVersion >> 32) & 0xFFFF);
        printf("Build:%u\n", (version.ullVersion >> 16) & 0xFFFF);
        printf("QFE:%u\n", version.ullVersion & 0xFFFF);
    }
    FreeLibrary(hInstance);
}
```

Comment: Is this work in the newer IE? I have heared that the newer version of `Microsoft Web Browser Control` is not inside `shdocvw.dll` anymore.

Comment: That's possible. I have updated my answer to read InternetExplorer COM object's server path. In recent version, it's indeed provided by ieframe.dll